# Recursive select mapping for tree view

Tags: c#, tail-recursion

I couldn't make this work, I want a component which uses select mapping but If children same type as main source I don't want to map select again that could go infinite, but If Its diferent then I have to map at first part.  this will be used at tree view component (in this scenario, we assume Children same type as main source; otherwhise we have to map another select)

```
ComponentUC.DataSource = SomeList.Select(t => 
                            new { 
                                    name = t.Title, 
                                    type = "folder", 
                                    additionalParameters = new { UId = t.UId }, 
                                    data = t.Children
                                }
                            );
```

**ComponentUC**

```
    public object DataSource;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object Result = ((List<dynamic>)DataSource).Select(t => Rec(t)).ToJson();
    }

    public object Rec(dynamic item)
    {
        if (item.Children.Count != 0)
        {
            if (DataSource.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[DataSource.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.Count()] == item.Children.GetType())
                item.Children = ((List<dynamic>)item.Children).Select(r => Rec(r));

            return
                new
                {
                    name = item.name,
                    type = item.type,
                    additionalParameters = item.additionalParameters,
                    data = item.Children
                };

        }
        else
        {
            return
                new
                {
                    name = item.name,
                    type = item.type,
                    additionalParameters = item.additionalParameters
                };
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can't/shouldn't return anonymous types like that.

Comment: any suggestion how should it be done?

Comment: return an instance of a class.